# Как выйти из vim в консоль для выполнения команды с возможностью возвращения в редактор?

Tags: linux, vim

Можно выполнять команду таким образом:

```
:!pwd
```

Однако, можно выполнить определенную команду и откроется консоль, где можно выполнять какие душе вздумается команды и потом выполнить `exit` - откроется `vim` со всеми вкладками.
Подскажите пожалуйста эту команду.

Comment: ^Z а для возврата `fg` чем не подходит?

Comment: @avp Можно и так, не знал - сталкивался только с командой и не мог ее вспомнить. Спасибо!

Comment: А я думаю, что ^Z это команд в vi (он же наверняка работает с терминалом в raw-mode, т.е. драйвер tty на ^Z, ^C и т.п. не реагирует)

Comment: Автор, а Вы пользуетесь общей history для всех шеллов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из документации (`:help :shell`):

> :sh[ell]                This command starts a shell.  When the shell exits
>   (after the "exit" command) you return to Vim.  The name for the shell command comes from 'shell' option.

т.е., для запуска оболочки надо ввести команду `:shell` (или, сокращённо, `:sh`).

Comment: Это запуск нового shell, а не выход в предыдущий (откуда запускался vim)

Comment: @avp, это создаёт какие-то проблемы?

Comment: Мне нет (использую emacs). Проблемы будут, если он захочет (маловероятно) воспользоваться переменными в шелле из которого запускал vi

Comment: @avp, `$ export a=b; vim`, затем `:shell`, в открывшемся экземпляре оболочки: `$ echo $a`. получил ответ: `b`. я что-то сделал не так?

Comment: С env, естественно, проблем не будет. А вот с history будут.

Comment: @avp, если вы до сих пор не пользуетесь [общей историей для всех экземпляров оболочки](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/110559), то мы идём к вам!

Comment: А ведь не пользуюсь (tl;dr). Что есть "из коробки", то и ем (думаю, большинство живет так же)

Comment: Более того, я тут подумал и понял, что меня такое будет раздражать. Все же привык, что в каждом окне своя история.

Comment: @avp, непривычное всегда (поначалу) раздражает.